# Weird patch on reflective spheres on planes in raytracer

Tags: python, raytracing

I am writing a small raytracer in python , everything was working fine but when i implemented plane geometry then the reflective spheres are getting weird patches on lower bottom. image below:

*I guess this is happening because of some error in calculating lighting with wrong normals? but i am unable to figure out exactly what.*

EDIT: When I moved the plane a unit down this disappeared, could it be because of point light above the spheres? to check this I removed all the lights but still, I am getting this patch.

[image]

code to find palne-ray intersection:

```
class Plane(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color, y=0, specular=-1, reflective=0):
        self.specular = specular
        self.reflective = reflective
        self.center = Vec3(0,y,0)
        self.normal = Vec3(0,-1,0)
        self.color = color

    def intersect_at_point(self, origin, ray):

        denom = ray.dot(self.normal)

        if abs(denom) > 0.0001:
            diff  = self.center - ray
            t = diff.dot(self.normal) / denom

            if t > 0.0001:
                return t
        return None
```

trace ray function.

```
def trace_ray(self, origin, direction, t_min, t_max, depth):



    closest_object, closest_t = self.closest_intersection(origin, direction, t_min, t_max)

    if closest_object == None:
        return Vec3(173/255, 216/255, 230/255)

    # Compute local color
    P = origin + closest_t * direction  # Compute intersection
    N = P - closest_object.center  # Compute  normal at intersection
    N = N / N.mag()
    local_color = closest_object.color * self.compute_light(P, N)

    # If we hit the recursion limit or the object is not reflective, we're done
    r = closest_object.reflective
    if depth <= 0 or r <= 0:
        return local_color

    # Compute the reflected color
    R = self.reflect_ray(-1*direction, N)
    reflected_color = self.trace_ray(P, R, 0.001, math.inf, depth - 1)

    return local_color * (1 - r) + reflected_color * r
```

closest intersection method.

```
  def closest_intersection(self, O, D, t_min, t_max):
        closest_t = math.inf
        closest_object = None

        for object in self.world.objects:
            t1, t2 = object.intersect_at_point(O, D)

            if (t_min < t1 < t_max) and t1 < closest_t:
                closest_t = t1
                closest_object = object

            if (t_min < t2 < t_max) and t2 < closest_t:
                closest_t = t2
                closest_object = object

        for plane in self.world.planes:

            t = plane.intersect_at_point(O,D)

            if t and (t_min < t < t_max) and t < closest_t:
                    closest_t = t
                    closest_object = plane

        return closest_object, closest_t
```

Calculate light method.

```
def compute_light(self, Point, Normal):

    i = 0.0
    P = Point
    N = Normal

    for light in self.world.lights:
        if light.type == 'ambient':
            i += light.intensity
        else:
            if light.type == 'point':
                L = light.position - P
                t_max = 1

            if light.type == 'directional':
                L = light.direction
                t_max = math.inf

            # Shadow check
            shadow_sphere, shadow_t = self.closest_intersection(P, L, 0.001, t_max)
            if shadow_sphere != None:
                continue

            n_dot_l = N.dot(L)

            if n_dot_l > 0:
                # print(f'light intensity {light.intensity}')
                i+= light.intensity * n_dot_l / (N.mag() * L.mag())

    return i
```

Comment: I think the value of t_min is very huge. Try to reduce the value of t_min.

Comment: @codetiger t_min's value is -1

Comment: In your class Plane, and the method intersect_at_point, you seem to need to divide by abs(denom), to cover the cases when dot product is negative (which is perfectly legit intersection). The problem looks like as if it caused from missing an intersection at certain points on the plane, especially when dot with the reflected ray & plane normal is -1. The failed intersection test yields background color on the sphere. I would also suggest singling out those pixels to see whether there are any divisions by 0, or any NaN, INF values.